# Cordova trouble while building

Tags: java, android, cordova, npm, command-line-interface

I am trying to build an app with Cordova for some time now, but it just doesn't work. In other projects earlier, everything was fine, and over night, Cordova simply stopped working normally. I am not new to Cordova but maybe a little unexperienced with certain errors which can occur.
So, when I am trying to build the app, the CLI says this:

```
D:\Visual Studio\Projects\XProjectX\BUILD-ORDNER\Jonthalie-App>cordova build android
cordova-android-support-gradle-release.after-prepare: No custom version found in config.xml - using plugin default
cordova-android-support-gradle-release.before-prepare: No custom version found in config.xml - using plugin default
Android Studio project detected
cordova-android-support-gradle-release.after-prepare: No custom version found in config.xml - using plugin default
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

I just don't understand what is going on, especially in the last two lines.

If I check the requirements, though, it does this:

```
D:\Visual Studio\Projects\XProjectX\BUILD-ORDNER\Jonthalie-App>cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Cannot read property 'version' of null
```

Everything should be up-to-date: JDK, NPM, Cordova, Android Studio etc...

I would be glad to get some help, as this problem drives me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lock file: rm .\package-lock.json

As per [link](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/298)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Cordova project and run it. You will see if the problem is in this project or in your global environment.

```
cordova create myApp
cd myApp
cordova platform add android
cordova run android
```

I suspect a problem of environnment's variable. 
Check JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME and your PATH entries.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-environment-variables